# Using Moq how do you get access the attributes of the returned explicit type

Tags: f#, moq

The Interfaces and etc. are setup using Moq and everything is working as expected but I can't determine how to access the attributes of my return types if they're not primitive data types. E.g. a string or integer return I have no issue acquiring.

In my example below the return of my method if called direct is an ActionResult Type and I can clearly see all the attributes returned from my mocked ApiController but it's not as simple as drilling down to access the members.

[image: The Code Sample Snippet]

In the returned value; first I have my declared variable (value) followed by Moq's Invoke method, then the generator and lastly in this example; the loginRequest which initiated the call and the "treasure" I'm trying to acquire referred to as @this

Since all this is dynamically generated at runtime I obviously can't call the members or attributes of the return during design-time unless there is some way to explicitly cast the return to the expected object on the returned value. Which would ideally be my first choice if its possible.

Is that possible or how should I otherwise be acquiring access directly to @this?

I'm new to both F# and Moq

Comment: What is the type of `value`? Based on your screenshot, it seems that this is actually an `Async<IActionResult>`, so you will only be able to access the result if you bind it using `let!` in the async block...

Comment: Thanks that was good solid advice and it worked to provide more direct access to the return of the method but I loose a lot of the other stuff. Like the Response object and all the other attributes on the call such as the RouteData, Url and etc. Although in the example the latter 2 mentioned are null. Still I want to acquire access to all the info in the @this reference

Comment: @TomasPetricek disregard my prior comment... I'm being stupid. What you said is actually the answer I was looking for. Sorry, I've obviously spent too much time on this code and can't see the forest for the trees.